# How can I separate my content on powershell?

Tags: powershell

This is my code: It runs correctly but it prints my content together. I was told to use the Write-ouput command and write an empty string but its not coming out right. Does anyone have any suggestions

```
$file1='/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs/dognames.txt'
$file2='/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats/catnames.txt'
$fileExist = (Test-Path -Path $file1) -AND (Test-Path -Path $file2)

if ($fileExist -eq $True) {
    $file_content = Get-Content -Path $file1
    Write-output -InputObject $file_content

   $file_content = Get-Content -Path $file2
    Write-output -InputObject $file_content
    Add-Content -Path "/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats/catnames.txt"      
-Value "Sammy"
    Add-Content -Path "/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats/catnames.txt" 
-Value "Luna"
    Get-Content -Path "/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats/catnames.txt" } else {
    Write-output -Inputobject "Unable to access one or more files"  }
```

Comment: You just want a blank line between each line?

Comment: Not necessarily each line just each file content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put powershell's implicit output to work for you and enclose it all in a subexpression `$(...)` then you can combine all the lines as you desire and output once. Add the `-Passthru` parameter of `Set-Content` and you don't need to read the file again after writing.

```
$file1='/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs/dognames.txt'
$file2='/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats/catnames.txt'
$fileExist = (Test-Path -Path $file1) -AND (Test-Path -Path $file2)

if ($fileExist -eq $True){
    $(Get-Content -Path $file1
    ""
    Get-Content -Path $file2
    "Sammy"
    "Luna") | Set-Content -Path "/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats/catnames.txt" -PassThru
} else {
    "Unable to access one or more files"  
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the Writeoutput command too? I'm required to use it in my coding

Comment: Yes it is essentially using write-output already. It gains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$file1='/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/dogs/dognames.txt'
$file2='/Users/raelynsade/Documents/cpt180stuff/pets/cats/catnames.txt'
$fileExist = (Test-Path -Path $file1) -AND (Test-Path -Path $file2)

if ($fileExist) 
{
    #content to dog file
    Get-Content -Path $file1
    " "

    #content to cat file with new values added
    Add-Content -Path $file2 -Value "Sammy" ,"Luna"
    Get-Content -Path $file2
} 
else 
{
    "Unable to access one or more files"  
}
```